# datetime (fmtcount) problem with \ordinalnum

Tags: numbering, superscripts, datetime

I'm using `\ordinalnum` with `datetime` package (the same with `fmtcount` package), but in french, the height & the size of the superscript using `\ordinalnum` are different from those of (for exemple) `\formatdate`, or using classical `\up{}` or `\ieme`.

I'd like to use something like `\ordinalnum` for personal commands, because it's very convenient, but with the result like `\up{ème}` for ordinal numbers different of 1 (in french : 1er, 2ème, 3ème…) : good height, good size of superscript & with de diacritic `ème`.

So, I imagine two solutions :

- order a change for the `\ordinalnum` fonction to these standards (2ème)
- find another convenient fonction for ordinal numbers…

Thanks for your help

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}                    
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}        %\usepackage{fmtcount}
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle}]{Adobe Garamond Pro}
\begin{document}
2\up{ème}, \ordinalnum{2}, \formatdate{1}{4}{2014}. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Comment aside: in French the correct abbreviation for 2ème, 3ème, &c. should be 2\textsuperscript{e}, 3\textsuperscript{e}, &c., (for which `frenchb` from  `babel` has shortcut commands, but certainly not \textup{eme/ème}. Take a look at the `Règles typographiques de L'Imprimerie nationale`.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for your advise, it's true, & I like this very useful book. But for some publication, they ask these kind of superscript…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\ordinalnum` uses `\textsuperscript`; you can easily change it so that `\up` is used instead. There's also a mistake, because for masculine ordinals “ème” should be used as well as for feminine ordinals.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}

% use \up instead of \textsuperscript
\renewcommand{\fmtord}[1]{\up{#1}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% fix a glitch in `fmtcount` that has “eme”
% for masculine ordinals, instead of ème
\patchcmd{\@ordinalMfrench}{eme}{ème}{}{}
\makeatother

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={OldStyle}]{Linux Libertine O} 

\begin{document}
2\up{ème}, \ordinalnum{2}, \formatdate{1}{4}{2014}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If, according to Bernard's advice, you want abbreviated superscripts, just set the relevant option.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\usepackage[dayofweek]{datetime}

\fmtcountsetoptions{abbrv}

% use \up instead of \textsuperscript
\renewcommand{\fmtord}[1]{\up{#1}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% fix a glitch in `fmtcount` that has “eme”
% for masculine ordinals, instead of ème
\patchcmd{\@ordinalMfrench}{eme}{ème}{}{}
\makeatother

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={OldStyle}]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
2\up{e}, \ordinalnum{2}, \formatdate{1}{4}{2014}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent ! Thank you very much for this complete answer.